# Query to a simple strings array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT container.category FROM `mybucket` as location
UNNEST location.partsContainers container
WHERE container.category IS NOT null
```

it gives me json:

```
[{
    "category": "0028H3:WV CUTTING EDGE AXIAL REAM TRAY"
},
{
    "category": "AVENTURA OASYS 1-2"
}, ... etc.
```

but what I need it a flat array of strings:

```
["0028H3:WV CUTTING EDGE AXIAL REAM TRAY",
 "AVENTURA OASYS 1-2",
   ... etc
]
```

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

you can use ARRAY_AGG:

```
SELECT RAW ARRAY_AGG(container.category)
FROM `mybucket` as location
UNNEST location.partsContainers container
WHERE container.category IS NOT null
```

Comment: this is close to what I want. It creates an array with an object, with a unnamed key in it, which contains the array I need. How can I make the array to be at the top level? right now it's: `[
  {
    "$1": [
      "CAT1","CAT2", "etc."`

Comment: the reason I need it to be completely flat is to be able to merge it (UNION ALL) with another query, and need a flat structure in the end that would cope well with paging (OFFSET and LIMIT)

Comment: Have you tried to specify not to return keys in the result, just values?

Comment: @user1697575 I'm not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: @Agzam, I added the 'RAW' to address your first comment.